# RSpec + Devise + override update_with_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having some troubles to test update_with_password method from devise which I overrided on my User model.

I'm using Rails 3.2, Devise 2.2.3 and Rspec-rails 2.13

Here's what my user model update_with_password method looks like:

```
#app/model/user.rb

def update_with_password(params, *options)
  if encrypted_password.blank?
    update_attributes(params, *options)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Here is my spec:

```
#spec/model/user_spec.rb

describe "#update_with_password" do
  context "when encrypted password is blank" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user_via_facebook)
      @user.save(validate: false)
      @facebook_profile = FactoryGirl.create(:facebook_profile, user: @user)
    end

    it "updates user attributes without asking current password" do
      @user.update_with_password(params: {first_name: "New First Name"})
      @user.first_name.should eql "New First Name"
    end

  end
end
```

And this is the error I'm getting after running the spec:

```
User#update_with_password when encrypted password is blank updates user attributes without asking current password
  Failure/Error: @user.update_with_password(params: {first_name: "New First Name"})
    ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
      Can't mass-assign protected attributes: params
```

How should I test this method?. There's something that I'm missing and I can't figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want

```
@user.update_with_password({first_name: "New First Name"})
```

instead of

```
@user.update_with_password(params: {first_name: "New First Name"})
```